# How can I toggle an embed twitter feed from light to dark?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter, darkmode

I used CSS to toggle a switch from a moon icon to a sun icon depending on what mode is active. The same logic is not working when I try to do the same for the Twitter feed. The website for development is dev.salvetri.com if that helps understand more context. The replit is public and is here: https://replit.com/@dartydan/Sal-Vetri?v=1

CSS

```
.twitter div.darkfeed a.twitter-timeline {
  opacity: 0;
}

body.dark .twitter div.darkfeed a.twitter-timeline {
  opacity: 1;
}

body.dark .twitter div.lightfeed a.twitter-timeline {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

HTML

```
<container class="twitter">
  <div class="lightfeed">
    <a
    class="twitter-timeline"
    data-lang="en"
    data-width=275px
    data-height=auto
    data-theme="light"
    href=""
    >Tweets by </a>
  </div>
  <div class="darkfeed">
    <a
    class="twitter-timeline"
    data-lang="en"
    data-width=275px
    data-height=auto
    data-theme="dark"
    href=""
    >Darkmode Tweets by </a>
  </div>
</container>
```

JavaScript

```
const body = document.querySelector('body'),
sidebar = body.querySelector('nav'),
toggle = body.querySelector(".toggle"),
searchBtn = body.querySelector(".search-box"),
modeSwitch = body.querySelector(".toggle-switch"),
modeText = body.querySelector(".mode-text");

toggle.addEventListener("click" , () =\>{
sidebar.classList.toggle("close");
})

searchBtn.addEventListener("click" , () =\>{
sidebar.classList.remove("close");
})

modeSwitch.addEventListener("click" , () =\>{
body.classList.toggle("dark");

    if(body.classList.contains("dark")){
        modeText.innerText = "Light mode";
    }else{
        modeText.innerText = "Dark mode";
        
    }

});
```

Targeting the `body.dark` has worked in other areas. Confused why it won't work here. Feel like I'm missing something really simple...

Answer (score 0):

can you make twitter feed to dark with 'direct live edit' css ?
just a simple enable/disable.

just look this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGwdw.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9FQ1.jpg

just add to js light div 'dom' ; change complete 'light' div display:none;

it should be.